# Session is not working as expected

Tags: laravel, session

Following is my middleware where I am setting some content on every request. For example cms_content in 'cms' session which I need to access in a helper to show the content in blade template.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Repositories\EloquentCountryRepository;
use App\Repositories\EloquentCmsContentRepository;
use Closure;
use Location;
use Session;

class SetDefaultLanguage
{
    // Instance of App\Repositories\EloquentCountryRepository;
    public $country;

    // Instance of App\Repositories\EloquentCmsContentRepository;
    public $cmsContent;

    /**
    *
    * Initialize dependencies
    */
    public function __construct(EloquentCountryRepository $country, EloquentCmsContentRepository $cmsContent)
    {
        $this->country    = $country;
        $this->cmsContent = $cmsContent;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //$location = Location::get(request()->ip());
        //$location = Location::get('146.185.171.157'); // Netherlands IP
        $location = Location::get('103.255.106.250');    // Indian IP

        $country = $this->country->getCountryByCode($location->countryCode);
        if($country->language_id){
            $contents = $this->cmsContent->getContentByLanguageId($country->language_id);
        }

        if($contents->isEmpty()){
            $contents = $this->cmsContent->getContentByLanguageId(1); // Default id for English
        }

        $contents = $contents->toArray();

        foreach($contents as $content){
            $cms[$content['meta_key']] = $content['meta_value'];
        }

        // Store CMS content into session
        session(['cms' => $cms, 'country_id' => $country->id]);
        //dd(session('cms'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Following is my helper method where i am accessing session data which i set in middleware.

```
public static function showDefault($key, $default_text = NULL){

    if(isset(session('cms')[$key])){
        return session('cms')[$key];
    }else{
        return $default_text;
    }
}
```

When I dd() session on the same middleware it seems working but in helper it is not showing latest data which i have set in middleware.

Please help me out this, i am trying to solve this issue since last 2 hours but dint get any solution.

Comment: Where are you calling `showDefault()`?

Comment: I think he is acessing in a blade template.

Comment: In blade template like showDefault('home', 'default value'); But I am not able to access latest data even i dd(session('cms')) in helper

Comment: show us your `Kernel` class, how did you register your middleware

Comment: @user3377819 you're reinventing the wheel. You can just use the session helper like this `session('cms.home', 'default value')`

Comment: protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLanguage::class,
    ];

Comment: @NikolaGavric please see my kernel

Comment: Update your question with full code from your Kernel

Comment: @NikolaGavric Thanks for pointing out that issue is in kernel :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution when i move my SetDefaultLanguage middleware from $middleware to web $middlewareGroups

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLanguage::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```